# Is there anyway to create a link to two paths in 1 ahref?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know this may seem like a weird question, but basically what I want to happen is whenever a link is shown and clicked, it should both go to the desired page and it should mark that notification unread.

So basically, I want to accomplish these two things in 1 link:

```
<%= link_to "#{activity.trackable.user.first_name} added a comment to '#{activity.trackable.node.name}'", activity.trackable.node, id: "unread-notification" %>
<%= link_to "Mark as Read", mark_as_read_activity_path(activity), method: :put, id: "mark-as-read" %>
```

Comment: You could use javascript to fire a request to `mark_as_read_activity_path` when the link is clicked. Or simply mark it as clicked when you visit the node in the nodes controller if it's not been marked as read already

Comment: @japed Do you have an example that you can show me? I am using `Turbolinks`, `jQuery.turbolinks()` and regular javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, you can look up more options for the ajax in the jquery docs, and there will undoubtedly be somethings you need to change for turbolinks.

```
<%= link_to "#{activity.trackable.user.first_name} added a comment to '#{activity.trackable.node.name}'", activity.trackable.node, data: { read_url: "#{mark_as_read_activity_path(activity)}" }, id: "unread-notification" %>
```

Here is the TL-friendly JS:

```
$(document).on("ready page:load", function(){
      $('#unread-notification').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).data('read-url');
        $.ajax({
          type: "PUT",
          url: url
        });
      });       
});
```

Comment: No worries, sorry for not providing TL friendly code but I don't use turbolinks myself.  Glad you got it working :)